# How do you create main-category/subcategory data model in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, class, struct

I'm creating a budget app and I'm new to programming.

I want to create an interface similar to the Apple Reminders app.

The first view is a list of main categories.

When you tap on a main category, the list of subcategories will appear.

I'm not sure whether to use a class or struct.

Here's how the code looks in my mind:

```
struct Category {
    
    let mainCategories: [String] = [
    
        "Income",
        "Housing",
        "Transportation",
        "Food",
        ...
    ]
    
    let incomeSubCategory: [String] = [
        
        "Salary",
        "Bonus",
        "Rental Income",
        ...

        
    ]
    
    let housingSubCategory: [String] = [
    
        "Mortgage/Rent",
        "Property Tax",
        "Homeowner's Insurance",
        ...
    
    ]
}
```

Am I going about this the right way? Or should I be using classes for inheritance?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I've tried using enums, but the data seems to be less flexible and accessible than structs.

Is it possible to make SubCategory a struct array within Category?

Like this:

```
struct Category {
    
    var name: String
    var color: UIColor
    var amount: Double
    var subCategories: [SubCategory]
    
}

struct SubCategory {
    var name: String
    var amount: Double
}



let categories = [

    Category(
        name: "Income",
        color: UIColor(rgb: Constants.green), subCategories: [name: "Paycheck", amount: 2500.00])
    ]
```

Comment: I think you should have enum instead of arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structs are probably fine.  Nothing you've described needs inheritance and you don't seem to be modifying the information.

What I would suggest is to keep related information together.  With that in mind, I would do something like:

```
struct Category {
    var name: String
    var subCategories: [String]
}

let categories = [Category(name: "Income", subCategories: ["Salary", "Bonus", "Rental Income"]),
                  Category(name: "Housing", subCategories: ["Mortgage/Rent", "Property Tax", "Homeowner's Insurance"])]
```

The advantage here is that, when you select a category, its related subcategories are implicitly available...no extra work to determine which ones match.

Comment: I've started implementing this struct and I'm having trouble accessing the subCategory data. I'm wondering if I can do something like add an array of a struct within a struct. I've updated the question.

Comment: Should work.  Init the subcategories using `subCategories: [SubCategory(name: "Paycheck", amount: 2500.00)]` then `print(categories[0].subCategories[0].name)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Enum`s instead of `struct/class`.

```
enum MainCategory: String, CaseIterable {
    case income, housing //...
}
enum IncomeSubCategory: String, CaseIterable {
    case salary, bonus //...
}
enum HousingSubCategory: String, CaseIterable {
    case rent, tax //...
}
```

The `CaseIterable` protocol conformance allows you to have the `allCases` array in case you need it to iterate over the values one by one. Like this:

```
MainCategory.allCases.forEach { print($0) }
```